# Confusion related to conditional distribution from latent variables and observations

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

I am a bit confused about how this expression was derived where Z are the latent variables and X the observations.

[image]

I think it is something like this but just to be sure

$p(z_{nk}|X,Z_{-nk}) = \frac{p(z_{nk}, X, Z_{-nk})}{p(X,Z_{-nk})}$

$= \frac{p(X|z_{nk},Z_{-nk})*p(z_{nk}|p(Z_{-nk})) * p(Z_{-nk})}{p(X|Z_{-nk})*p(Z_{-nk})}$

$\propto p(X|Z)*p(z_{nk}|Z_{-nk})$

Is it correct? My question is don't I need to set $z_{nk} = 1$ inside $p(X|Z)$ since $z_{nk}$ is a part of it?

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you have chosen a slightly different title for your question? Now there are two identically titled questions (cf. http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/65707/6633) posted by the same user within hours of each other.

Comment: @DilipSarwate. My bad Dilip. Should I change it? Because both of them are kind of similar

Comment: @user34790 Make title so that it matches the content. "I have a problem with ..." isn't a good title. "Conditional distribution from latent variables and observations" or something like this...